# Canvas too small to display Image in SWT

Tags: java, image, canvas, swt

I'm trying to use a Canvas to display an animated gif. I have the animation working, but the canvas is too small to see the entire image, and I cannot get it to resize.

I can't even get it to be the right size for the first frame, so the animation/threading code is being omitted. My code looks like:

```
Composite comp = new Composite(parent, SWT.None);
comp.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

final ImageLoader loader = new ImageLoader();
loader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("MYFILE.gif"));

final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(comp, SWT.None);
final Image image = new Image(Display.getCurrent(), loader.data[0]);

canvas.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
  public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
    e.gc.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
  }
});
```

The canvas area ends up being a tiny box of around 30x30, regardless of how big MYFILE.gif is. What the hell?

Anything I try to use to set the canvas size (setSize, setBounds, etc) does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `setPreferredSize`. The layout manager will call `setSize` and/or `setBounds` and clobber the values you have set, but it will try to respect preferred size if it can. You can also use `setMaximumSize` and `setMinimumSize` to control how the canvas will resize if the enclosing component is resized.

EDIT: For SWT you could try this:

```
GridData gridData = new GridData();
gridData.widthHint = imageWidth;
gridData.heightHint = imageHeight;
canvas.setLayoutData(gridData);
```

I'm not an SWT expert, but [the SWT documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html) seems helpful.

Comment: I'm using SWT 3.6 and I don't see any of those methods available in Canvas, Composite, or Shell.

Comment: Sorry, misread the question. This applies to Swing or AWT components.

Comment: Argh, I didn't think to set the width/height hints in the GridData. God SWT, you can be retarded sometimes. It works now at least.